# Voltage Flows in an Inductor

Tags: induction

> Pretend that a current increases across the left end to the right end of this inductor. I want to understand why the left edge is at a higher potential. This is my logic that contradicts that correct claim:

1) As current increases to the right, flux increases to the right

2) As flux increases, it changes. As flux changes, an EMF (and hence a current) are induced to counteract the flux's rightwards flow.

3) This induced emf flows leftwards

4) EMF flows end at regions of lower potential (or do they not?)*. Thus, the left hand side -- which is the destination of the induced emf -- is negative.

5) That leaves the right hand side at a higher potential.

[image: A current is increasing from the left end to the right end]

Comment: Voltage doesn't flow. Voltage = potential. Charge and current flows due to potential - from high to low. Changes in current through an inductor do result in a reverse emf (potential) that resists forward current flow. The faster the current changes, the higher the resistance. That's impedance (frequency dependent resistance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the idea of "flowing" EMF pointed out by docscience, the main flaw in your logic is point 4.  EMF is work per unit charge being done *by* the circuit elements *on* the current, so (to the extent that it makes sense to say the EMF has a direction), EMF "points" in the direction of the "push" on the current.  That is, EMF is positive when the push is in the same direction as the current, and negative when it is opposed to the current.  That means it points "uphill" in potential when the work is being done against some potential difference, not towards lower potential.  For example, a battery does work moving the current from the negative terminal to the positive; the emf pushes the current toward the higher-potential terminal. (It's what gets the charge up the hill.)  In a resistor, the EMF holds the current back, pushing it "upstream," and the upstream side of the resistor is at higher potential.  Same thing for the inductor: if the current is increasing, the emf impedes the increase, pushing the current, as you say, back upstream (to the left in your figure), but that means it's the upstream side (the left side) that is at higher potential.

To think of it another way, if the emf is doing work *against* the current, as in a resistor or in your inductor example, then the current *drops* in potential energy per unit charge (i.e. it drops in potential) as it crosses the circuit element.

Comment: No.in a circuit through which magnetic flux is changing potential doesnt even make sense.

Comment: Ever heard of the potential description of Maxwell's equations? There is an electrostatic potential and a magnetic vector potential. The electrostatic potential makes sense as long as we also include all emfs from the changing magnetic vector potential.

Comment: @Nanite :Reference?

Comment: @Paul : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Potential_field_approach . I guess the main point is that when there is a changing vector potential, then electric field is not just the gradient of the electrostatic potential.

Comment: @Paul It does if the magnetic flux is being produced by the circuit itself and not due to an external field.  If you put a voltmeter across the inductor, you will certainly measure a voltage drop.  Add up the potential differences around the circuit (including the one across the inductor) and you will still get 0.

Comment: @pwf ah I understand my mistake. I identified the left side of inductor as "negative", simply because I thought  that the inductor could be divided into a negative left half and a positive right half. I had this thought, because, using conventional current, current would flow left (from positive to negative) in the diagram. The polarization of the inductor has no bearing, however, on  the fact that induced current opposes the circuit's current. Thus, current leaving the inductor is at a lower potential than when it enters.